# Sitecore FileUtil.ZipFiles creating zip files from Media Library items

Tags: media-library

Is it possible to create a zip file using Sitecore `FileUtil.ZipFiles` where the files to be added are from the Media Library items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible wit `FileUtil` only.

What you can do is:

1. Add a reference to `Sitecore.Zip.dll`
2. Use `Sitecore.Zip.ZipWriter` class like that:

```
using (ZipWriter zw = new ZipWriter(FileUtil.MapPath("/test.zip")))
{
    var mediaItem = new MediaItem(item);
    zw.AddEntry(mediaItem.Name + "." + mediaItem.Extension, mediaItem.GetMediaStream());
}
```

Remember that your IIS process user must have write access to the folder where you want to create the zip file.